# Is it possible to pass view to ListView Adapter class?

Tags: android, listview, android-filter

I have a TextView and a ListView in my layout.I am doing a Filter operation and the results are set in ListView.If the result is null,then i want to set "No results" in my TextView.
Is it possible to pass the TextView through the constructor of the Adapter class so that i can set the text if result is null?

Comment: for that you can maintain one textview in your layout when result is none set textview visibilty to VISIBLE else GONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed my TextView through constructor and checked the result in publishResults and set the visibility accordingly

```
@Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {

        try{
        filteredModelItemsArray=new ArrayList<MarkerRowItem>();
        filteredModelItemsArray = (ArrayList<MarkerRowItem>) results.values;

        if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            noResultTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            noResultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setEmptyView()`.

1. On your layout, set the visibility of your `TextView` to `android:visibility="gone"`
2. On your activity, set the instance of your `TextView` to the `ListView` using `setEmptyView()`

   ```
   ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);
   listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.your_empty_text_view));
   ```